# curly brace in spring boot default property value

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my `application.yml` for my spring boot application I have this property:

```
apiKey: ${SECRET_ADYEN_API_KEY:djhksy{f7dsadasb}
```

The problem is that the API key contains a forward curly brace, which messes up the parsing of the key in the app. It becomes `${SECRET_ADYEN_API_KEY:djhksy{f7dsadasb}`, not simply `djhksy{f7dsadasb` which is the actual API key. How can I get around this? I tried escaping the `{` character with `\` and `\\` without luck.

Comment: are you really sure, "{" is there in your api key? generally I have never seen key contains braces n all. may be I could be wrong.

Comment: Did you try `${SECRET_ADYEN_API_KEY:'djhksy{f7dsadasb'}`? Also, putting any "secret" in plaintext there anyway would be a bad idea

Comment: priyranjan: I found it odd as well. but i double checked, and indeed it contains a curly brace.. Not so compatible ...

OneCricketeer: I did try that, but it didn't work .. I know plaintext secrets committed to version control is a no-no, but since it's not the production secret I chose to do it anyway, to not have to include setting secret in instructions for new developers wanting to run the project ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try separating the default value (djhksy{f7dsadasb) to a different property just like below, It is working for me :

```
default-secret-key: djhksy{f7dsadasb
apiKey: ${SECRET_ADYEN_API_KEY:${default-secret-key}}
```